# Intermittent 401 on Azure Key Vault access

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

This evening, we started noticing intermittent 401 UnAuthorized responses in Application Insights regarding Key Vault access ("/secrets"). Some requests succeed, about half of them (or more) are failing.

Is anyone else seeing the same behavior?

Comment: My team and I learned the hard way "don't hit azure key vault too much'.  1.  the expense (but not the biggest issue) (2) too many hits, denial your request issues.     We ended up implementing a cache-aside solution.. even "1 minute" of cache-aside expiration made a different.   obviously how long to cache-aside a secret is a balancing act.

Answer (score 0):

For random infrequent errors , please give some time and refresh to see the difference , it may be server or cache errors.

In other cases:
Please check :

1. If the keyvaults  from which the secrets is received has expired tokens/keys.
2. If their activation date is varied.
   Sometimes it may be due to subscription issue,
3. In that case make subscription that has to be  as default for current account that you are working on,

Please login into Azure CLI and list the accounts:

```
az account list --output table
```

Make the actual subscription which has the azure KeyVault as the default subscription:

```
az account set --subscription "<your subscription name>"
```

4. Also please make sure if the following are given correct:
   key vault tenant ID, Client ID ,Client secret (if used)
   And also Resource value to be corrrect:  `https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net` (URL encoded)

**Reference**: [troubleshooting-401 - Azure Key Vault | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rest-error-codes#troubleshooting-401)